# How do I transform $(\sin^2y + x \arctan y)y' = 1 $ to apply Lagrange's method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Orignal equation is:

$$(\sin^2y + x \arctan y)y' = 1 $$

It is very well seen that the equation is first-order non-linear one, so I wanted to use Lagrange's method here, but I do not know how to transform it to

$$y'+p(x)\cdot y = q(x)$$

which is standard form of the equation

Comment: What is $\tan^{-1}y$?  Is it $\arctan y$?

Comment: @xpaul, yes it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(\sin^2y + x \tan^{-1} y)\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 $$
HINT :

$\sin^2y + x \tan^{-1} y = \frac{dx}{dy} $
$$ \frac{dx}{dy}-x \tan^{-1} y =\sin^2y  $$
Consider the unknown function $x(y)$

To make it more evident, change of symbols : $\begin{cases} t\equiv y \\ u\equiv x\end{cases}$ 
$$ \frac{du}{dt}-u\tan^{-1} t  =\sin^2t  $$
This is a first order linear ODE to be solved for the function $u(t)$

Comment: Ah, it seems I got it, ohly had got confusion about what transformation yo've applied to get proper

$$ \frac{dx}{dy}-x \tan^{-1} y =\sin^2y  $$

equation?

Comment: +1 for brilliant answer. Just formally multiply by $dx/dy$.

Comment: @M.Mass : This is the derivative of the inverse function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation